# Centering images and overprint in Beamer

Tags: beamer, horizontal-alignment, overlays

I'm trying to create a `beamer` presentation with several images replacing each other on consecutive slides. I've gotten it to work with `overprint` and `\onslide`, but cannot get the images centered on the slide.

```
\begin{center}
  \begin{overprint}
    \onslide<2>\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{images/stack1.pdf}    
    \onslide<3>\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{images/stack2.pdf}
    \onslide<4>\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{images/stack3.pdf}
    \onslide<5>\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{images/stack4.pdf}
    \onslide<6>\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{images/stack5.pdf}
    \onslide<7>\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{images/stack6.pdf}
    \onslide<8>\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{images/stack7.pdf}
  \end{overprint}
\end{center}
```

Anything outside of the `overprint` environment gets properly centered, but not the images themselves.

Comment: AFAIK, the `overprint` environment acts as a box with the maximum size of any included content. Are all images the same size? Also just try `\centering` instead of the `center` environment, or place each `\includegraphics[..]{..}` into a `\centerline{..}` to manually center it (if it is supposed to be on a line of its own).

Comment: Thanks! \centerline{} did the trick! All images are of the same width, but not the same height; \centering doesn't help

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `overprint` environment has a fixed width which defaults to the `\textwidth` (or maybe the similar `\linewidth`) and can be given using the optional argument. The whole environment is then centered, not just the image(s) inside it, which are internally left aligned. Because the environment is already as wide as the given space the centering effectively doesn't change its placement. You need to center the images inside the `overprint` area instead (e.g. using `\centerline{\includegraphics[..]{..}}}`) *or* reduce the `overprint` environment to the image width manually so that it can be effectively centered.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Test}
  \begin{center}
  text before
  \pause
  \begin{overprint}%
    \onslide<2>\centerline{\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{images/stack1.pdf}}%
    \onslide<3>\centerline{\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{images/stack2.pdf}}%
    \onslide<4>\centerline{\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{images/stack3.pdf}}%
    \onslide<5>\centerline{\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{images/stack4.pdf}}%
    \onslide<6>\centerline{\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{images/stack5.pdf}}%
    \onslide<7>\centerline{\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{images/stack6.pdf}}%
    \onslide<8>\centerline{\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{images/stack7.pdf}}%
  \end{overprint}
  text after
  \end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

or

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Test}
    \begin{center}
  text before
  \pause

  \begin{overprint}[7cm]%
    \onslide<2>\includegraphics[width=7cm]{images/stack1.pdf}%
    \onslide<3>\includegraphics[width=7cm]{images/stack2.pdf}%
    \onslide<4>\includegraphics[width=7cm]{images/stack3.pdf}%
    \onslide<5>\includegraphics[width=7cm]{images/stack4.pdf}%
    \onslide<6>\includegraphics[width=7cm]{images/stack5.pdf}%
    \onslide<7>\includegraphics[width=7cm]{images/stack6.pdf}%
    \onslide<8>\includegraphics[width=7cm]{images/stack7.pdf}%
  \end{overprint}%

  text after
  \end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I replaced the `scale` key with `width` here to ensure that the images have the same width as the `overprint` environment. I prefer the first `\centerline` solution because you don't have to match any widths.